# Server does not respond to client connection request when launching it from terminal

Tags: qt

I am writing simple [Qt client-server](https://github.com/Zavrik94/MyServer) in Qt Creator. If I run it from Qt Creator it is working, but if i try `qmake-make` in source directory and run as `./MyServer`, then I get message server is listening but does not display connected clients and it is not responding to clients commands:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>
#include "myserver.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication serv(argc, argv);
    MyServer server;

    server.startServer();

    return serv.exec();
}
```

Here is **MyServer.h**:

```
#ifndef MYSERVER_H
#define MYSERVER_H

#include <QTcpServer>
#include "mythread.h"

class MyServer : public QTcpServer
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyServer(QObject *parent = 0);
    void startServer();
signals:

public slots:

protected:
    void incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor);

};

#endif // MYSERVER_H
```

and here is **MyServer.cpp**:

```
#include "myserver.h"
#include "mythread.h"

MyServer::MyServer(QObject *parent) :
    QTcpServer(parent)
{
}

void MyServer::startServer()
{
    if (!this->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1111))
    {
        qDebug() << "Could not start server";
    }
    else
    {
        qDebug() << "listen...";
    }
}

void MyServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";

    MyThread *thread = new MyThread(socketDescriptor, this);

    connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

    thread->start();
}
```

And here are **MyThread.h**:

```
#ifndef MYTHREAD_H
#define MYTHREAD_H

#include <QThread>
#include <QTcpSocket>
#include <QDebug>

class MyThread : public QThread
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MyThread(int SD, QObject *parent = 0);

    void run();

signals:
    void error(QTcpSocket::SocketError socketerror);

public slots:
    void readyRead();
    void disconnected();

private:
    QString answer(QString str);
    QString getDataParam(QString str);
    int getKeyParam(QString str);
    QTcpSocket *socket;
    int socketDescriptor;
    int key;
    QString data;
};

#endif
```

and **MyThread.cpp**:

```
#include "mythread.h"

MyThread::MyThread(int SD, QObject *parent) :
    QThread(parent)
{
    this->socketDescriptor = SD;
}

void MyThread::run()
{
    qDebug() << "Thread started";

    socket = new QTcpSocket();

    if(!socket->setSocketDescriptor(this->socketDescriptor))
    {
        emit error(socket->error());
        return;
    }

    connect(socket, SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readyRead()), Qt::DirectConnection);
    connect(socket, SIGNAL(disconnected()), this, SLOT(disconnected()));

    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Client connected";
    exec();
}

int MyThread::getKeyParam(QString str)
{
    QString temp;
    int res;
    bool ok;
    int start = str.indexOf('(');
    int end = str.indexOf(',', start);
    if (start == -1 || end == -1)
        return (-2);
    start++;
    temp = str.mid(start, end - start);
    res = temp.toInt(&ok, 10);
    if (ok == false)
           return (-1);
    return (res);
}

QString MyThread::getDataParam(QString str)
{
    QString temp;
    int start = str.indexOf(',');
    int end = str.indexOf(')', start);
    if (start == -1 || end == -1)
        return (NULL);
    start++;
    temp = str.mid(start, end - start);
    return (temp);
}

QString MyThread::answer(QString str)
{
   if (QString::compare(str, "hello", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 1)
       return ("Hello i`m your echo server\n");
   else if (QString::compare(str, "--help", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 1)
       return ("you can use this commands:\nhello\nget_param\nset_param(key,data)\ndisc\n");
   else
       return ("can`t find this command. use \"--help\" and try again\n");
   return (NULL);
}

void MyThread::readyRead()
{
    QString str = socket->readAll();
    QByteArray array;
    if (QString::compare(str, "disc", Qt::CaseInsensitive) == 1)
        socket->close();
    if (str.startsWith("set_param"))
    {
         data = MyThread::getDataParam(str);
         key =  MyThread::getKeyParam(str);
    }
    else if (str.startsWith("get_param"))
    {
        if (key == -1)
            array.append("key not number\n");
        else if (key == -2 || data == NULL)
            array.append("wrong, use \"set_param(key,data)\" correctly\n");
        else if (data == "" || key == 0)
            array.append("no param\n");
        else
            array.append("param key:" + QString::number(key) + "\nparam data:" + data +"\n");
    }
    else
    {
      array.append(MyThread::answer(str));
    }
    socket->write(array);
}

void MyThread::disconnected()
{
    qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Disconnected";

    socket->deleteLater();
    exit(0);
}
```

Comment: Show us `MyServer`.

Comment: The first thing I see, that `exit(0)` looks suspicious in `void MyThread::disconnected()`. I think it should not be there.